# BATCH - Create a backup, then after n created, delete old backups

Tags: batch-file, backup

Premise:

Script to run every n seconds which will create a backup of a defined file to a defined location.
After n backups have been created, clean(delete) out dated ones.

Problem:

I have managed to get working a version of this to backup a folder and delete older verisons, but when I attempt this with a specific file "no files are found".
I've scratched my head for several hours about this now, I'm probably missing something small.
I do not simply want to delete all .xlsx files, for example, as there is the possibility that there will be multiple different .xlsx files in the Target folder.
I only want to delete old versions of "File1" if there are 3 newer versions available.

Is there someway I can do this? I've tried with a wildcard, as you can see below, but no luck...

Help please :(

Vars:

```
- Schedule=60 (Time inseconds between each backup)
- NumFiles=3 (How many backup versions to keep)
- File1Path=D:\Source (Location to copy files from)
- File1=backmeup.xlsx (Filename & extension)
- BackupPath=D:\Target (Location to copy files to)
```

Code snippet:

```
@echo off
Color 02
mode con: cols=150 lines=25

:Start
SET Schedule=60
SET NumFiles=3
SET File1Path=D:\Source
SET File1=backmeup.xlsx
SET BackupPath=D:\Target

echo Press any key to begin.
pause >nul
echo.

:Single1
FOR /F %%a IN ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime ^| FIND "."') DO SET DTS=%%a
SET DateTime=%DTS:~0,4%-%DTS:~4,2%-%DTS:~6,2%@%DTS:~8,2%%DTS:~10,2%

IF DEFINED File1Path (
    xcopy "%File1Path%\%File1%" "%BackupPath%\_BACKUP_%DateTime%_%File1%*" /h /d /y /c /i /q /r /k >nul
    ( for /f "skip=%NumFiles% delims=" %%F in ('dir "%BackupPath%" /b /a:-dh /o:-d "%File1%"') do echo del /q "%BackupPath%\%%F"
    ( goto SingleDone ))) ELSE ( goto End )

:SingleDone
echo Backups created - %DateTime%
TIMEOUT /T %Schedule% /NOBREAK
GOTO Single1

:End
echo Something is not defined or incomplete.
echo Press any key to exit.
pause >nul
exit
```

Comment: First, create a new backup; second, use a `for /F` loop that parses the output of `dir /B /A:-D /O:-D /T:C "_BACKUP_*_%File1%.xlsx"` (enumerate backups of `File1.xlsx`, sorted per creation date, newest first) and add a counter (`set /A COUNT=0` before the loop and `set /A COUNT+=1` in the loop to increment it); if the counter value (`COUNT`) exceeds a certain limit, delete the backup file (`if` condition); remember to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for reading the counter value...

Answer (score 0):

To make a backup, the easy answer is to just use `xcopy`. To delete old files/directories, use the below command

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* -d <number of days> -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: Days are no good, this is to run during a shift to keep backups of shared excel sheets that regularly break.

Comment: How often do you need it to backup?

Comment: I say in the post. It's a choice in seconds.

    SET Schedule=60

It could be 60, or 1000

Comment: @J.Burton Maybe do something like this in C#, doing this in cmd is going to absolutely hammer your processing power. Not only are you copying a large excel sheet over the network, you are also deleting copies of the previous excel sheet no matter if it's changed or not, all the while running your tasks Synchronously. If you want I'll give you a hand but this as a batch script isn't going to perform as well as an ASync C# application